# preventDefault() on a multi-select, different behavior on Firefox - IE - Chrome

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm struggling with the mouse events on a select multiple. I didn't expect to get this difference in behavior across browsers in 2015...

I'm basically trying to simulate the Ctrl+Click only with a click, for easy use. It was working on Chrome, using `preventDefault()`, by cancelling the default behaviour (select current option and deselect others)

```
select.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {        
    evt.preventDefault();        
    evt.target.selected = !evt.target.selected;

    return false;
}, true);
```

Here is the fiddle, you can check with different browsers:
https://jsfiddle.net/fzvkw1xv/

- Chrome -> works as expected
- Firefox -> It's like `preventDefault()` doesn't
  do anything. Other options get unchecked.
- IE 11 -> No option get
  selected at all

What I want to achieve is full control over the multi-select to make a better user experience.

I couldn't find any documentation related to this, I don't know which browser is the buggy one, or what the standard expected behavior is. Any info on this would be much appreciated. I'm starting to think about making checkboxes look like a multi-select box.

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? Your jsfiddle example seems to be quite synthetic.

Comment: I'm trying to get the same functionality that CTRL+Click does on a multiselect box. But without using CTRL. The point is the difference across browser, that is driving me nuts

Comment: Why don't you use some JS UI framework like JQuery not to going crazy with cross-browsing issues?

Comment: Because I like to play and learn. Because I want to push my limits. Because glory is only for the brave... or maybe because I didn't find any suitable plugin. Do you know any?

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers has different ways to handle events.

There is event bubbling besides event capturing. You need to stop it too.

Discover event propagation model: http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

Try more wide solution:

```
function (event) {
  event = event || window.event // Cross-browser event

  event.preventDefault(); // Stop event capturing

  // Stop event bubbling
  if (event.stopPropagation) { // W3C standard variant
      event.stopPropagation();
  } else { // IE variant
      event.cancelBubble = true
  }

  return false;
}
```

http://javascript.info/tutorial/default-browser-action

Comment: Adding the stopPropagation() doesn't help. BTW, this is event capturing, not bubbling.

Comment: Check updated snippet. `preventDefault()` stops capturing and `stopPropagation()` stops bubbling.

Comment: @JavRok, in what browsers code does not work for now?

Comment: I did the test myself, and stopPropagation still doesn't fix anything. Can you please do a fork on my jsFiddle on show it to me?